# First Unit Tests! ASP.NET MVC with Repositories causing errors

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, justmock

I am very new to Unit Testing, so I am starting on my first set of tests today. I am using the Library `JustMock` from Telerik. Though any unit testing information is good. I am having a bit of trouble with an interface service that passes through my method. Below is my `MembershipController.Register(model)` method...

```
    [CaptchaValidator]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(Models.Membership.Registration model)
    {
        // just for good mesure, truncate any spaces that are given 
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(model.Email, @"\s", "");

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the User and return any applicable status that has to do
            // with the result.
            var createStatus = membershipService.RegisterMember(model.Email, model.Password);

            // if the member is able to be created successfully, log them in now and begin the
            // authentication portion of the registration, otherwise, display the registration
            // errors and return to the view.
            if (createStatus == Membership.MemberCreateStatus.Success)
            {
                formsAuthentication.SignIn(model.Email, false /* createPersistentCookie */);
                return RedirectToAction("Success");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", Membership.Validator.ErrorCodeToString(createStatus));
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

And here is the paltry test I am trying to run...

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Register_Post_ReturnsRedirectOnSuccess()
    {
        // Arrange
        var controller = Mock.Create<Web.Controllers.MembershipController>();

        var repository = Mock.Create<Membership.IMembershipService>();

        Mock.Arrange(() => repository.RegisterMember("acceptible@email.com", "acceptiblePassword")).Returns(Membership.MemberCreateStatus.Success);

        // Model
        var model = new Web.Models.Membership.Registration
        {
            Email = "acceptible@email.com",
            Password = "acceptiblePassword",
            ConfirmPassword = "acceptiblePassword"
        };

        // Act
        var result = controller.Register(model);

        // Assert
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(RedirectToRouteResult));

    }
```

The test fails because `membershipService` is resolving as null. I'm not sure what to do here. This is my first forray into the Unit Testing aspect of ASP.NET MVC. Can anyone give me some advice?

I am using `Ninject` to inject `IMembershipService` through the Constructor. It is implemented by the class `MembershipService`. The code runs fine when I run it, but the unit tests fail.

Comment: I don't see you passing `repository` anywhere into your controller. Normally you would have `IMembershipService` as a parameter in your controller's constructor that you can then pass in when needed or use MVC's Service Locator to grab the Ninject instance and pass it in.

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. I was not creating the service. Can you post that as your answer so I can give credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see you passing repository anywhere into your controller. Normally you would have IMembershipService  as a parameter in your controller's constructor that you can then pass in when needed or use MVC's Service Locator to grab the Ninject instance and pass it in.

`:)`